# What does $End_{M_n(D)}(D^n)$ mean? Where D is a division ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

What does $End_{M_n(D)}(D^n)$ mean? (D is division ring)

I know it's the homomorphisms from $D^n$ to itself, but what role does ${M_n(D)}$ play? Does that mean over the nxn matrices over D? What does that actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $D^n$ is a $M_n(D)$ module.

By $End_{M_n(D)}D^n$  we mean $M_n(D)$ homomorphisms of $D^n$ i.e., module homomorphisms..

Comment: I see, so in a way the ${M_n(D)}$ is simply there to let us know that $D^n$ is a ${M_n(D)}$ module?

Comment: Yes.. More over, the morphisms are module homomorphisms.... Not just ring homomorphisms...